# Aggregate based on conditions r

Tags: r, aggregate

I have dataset which contains four columns`X1` (id number), `X2` (Datetime), `X3` (Datetime), `X4` (Duration) which is as follows

```
test2 = structure(list(X1 = c(549395L, 678018L, 706197L, 549395L, 775731L, 789858L, 845277L, 936749L, 845277L, 954953L), X2 = c("6/16/2014", "9/16/2014", "2/12/2014", "6/16/2014", "8/29/2014", "2/26/2014", "4/7/2014", "2/14/2014", "5/18/2014", "3/5/2014"), X3 = c("6/4/2014 11:10", "9/16/2014 10:23", "2/12/2014 12:21", "6/4/2014 11:10", "8/29/2014 8:51", "2/26/2014 12:49", "4/7/2014 13:59", "2/14/2014 12:08", "4/7/2014 01:39", "3/5/2014 10:14"), X4 = c(8L, 21L, 10L, 72L, 39L, 14L, 41L, 31L, 43L, 24L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

       X1        X2              X3 X4
1  549395 6/16/2014  6/4/2014 11:10  8
2  678018 9/16/2014 9/16/2014 10:23 21
3  706197 2/12/2014 2/12/2014 12:21 10
4  549395 6/16/2014  6/4/2014 11:10 72
5  775731 8/29/2014  8/29/2014 8:51 39
6  789858 2/26/2014 2/26/2014 12:49 14
7  845277  4/7/2014  4/7/2014 13:59 41
8  936749 2/14/2014 2/14/2014 12:08 31
9  845277 5/18/2014  4/7/2014 01:39 43
10 954953  3/5/2014  3/5/2014 10:14 24
```

What I want to accomplish is this

1. If the `X1` (ID numbers) have same date and time in `X3` then replace their corresponding  `X4` with `max` of those `x4`. For example, Id Number (549395 ) has same date and time (x3) 6/4/2014 11:10, so `X4` should be replaced by `max(72, 8) ...72`.
2. if the `X1` (ID numbers) have same date but different time then replace their corresponding `X4` with `sum` of their individual x4s. For example, Id Number (845277) has same same date (4/7/2014) different time (13:59 , 1:39)  so `X4` should be `sum (43,41) = 84`.

The output should look like this.

```
       X1        X2              X3  X4
1  549395 6/16/2014  6/4/2014 11:10  72
2  678018 9/16/2014 9/16/2014 10:23  21
3  706197 2/12/2014 2/12/2014 12:21  10
4  549395 6/16/2014  6/4/2014 11:10  72
5  775731 8/29/2014 8/29/2014  8:51  39
6  789858 2/26/2014 2/26/2014 12:49  14
7  845277  4/7/2014  4/7/2014 13:59  84
8  936749 2/14/2014 2/14/2014 12:08  31
9  845277 5/18/2014  4/7/2014 01:39  84
10 954953  3/5/2014  3/5/2014 10:14  24
```

I tried using aggregate function but the results are no where near what I want to accomplish. So need help.

#### New data:

```
test2=   structure(list(X1 = c(1491930L, 3162932L, 3162932L, 4092879L, 
5374073L, 7427514L, 2377939L, 2377939L, 4081399L), X2 = structure(c(16073, 
16073, 16073, 16073, 16074, 16073, 16081, 16081, 16077), class = "Date"), 
X3 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 7L), .Label = c("2014-01-03 10:11", 
"2014-01-03 11:1", "2014-01-03 11:44", "2014-01-03 8:47", 
"2014-01-03 9:40", "2014-01-04 11:7", "2014-01-07 8:42", 
"2014-01-11 2:58", "2014-01-11 2:6"), class = "factor"), 
X4 = c(31, 26, 4, 32, 24, 132, 50, 16, 66)), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Desired result:

```
          X1         X2       date       time  X4
        1 1491930 2014-01-03 2014-01-03  8:47  31
        2 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03  9:40  30
        3 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 10:11  30
        4 4092879 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 11:44  32
        5 5374073 2014-01-04 2014-01-04  11:7  24
        6 7427514 2014-01-03 2014-01-03  11:1 132
        7 2377939 2014-01-11 2014-01-11   2:6  66
        8 2377939 2014-01-11 2014-01-11  2:58  66
        9 4081399 2014-01-07 2014-01-07  8:42  66
```

Comment: @RichardScriven boy that got out of control real quick :), I updated the question..hopeful it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option how you could do it using dplyr and tidyr. I included some date formatting which increases the length of the "pipe", but it would be worth it IMO. I'll mark those parts of the pipe as "optional".

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

test2 %>%
  separate(X3, into = c("date", "time"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.Date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d")), X2, date) %>%
  group_by(X1, date, time) %>%
  mutate(X4 = max(X4)) %>%
  group_by(X1, date) %>%
  mutate(X4 = ifelse(n_distinct(time) == 1L, X4, sum(X4))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  unite(X3, date:time, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(X3 = as.POSIXct(X3))
```

Using the **new** data set, this produces:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 4]

       X1         X2                  X3  X4
1 1491930 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 08:47:00  31
2 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 09:40:00  30
3 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 10:11:00  30
4 4092879 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 11:44:00  32
5 5374073 2014-01-04 2014-01-04 11:07:00  24
6 7427514 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 11:01:00 132
7 2377939 2014-01-11 2014-01-11 02:06:00  66
8 2377939 2014-01-11 2014-01-11 02:58:00  66
9 4081399 2014-01-07 2014-01-07 08:42:00  66
```

I start off by separating the original X3 column into two columns data and time (using separate from tidyr) and formatting columns X2 and date as a real Date format. Next, I group the data by X1, date and time and then replace the X4 with the maximum X4 within each date/time group. Then I group the data only by X1 and date and check if the number of unique time values is 1. If so, return X4 unchanged, otherwise, return the sum of X4. What follows is ungrouping the data, uniting the columns date and time back to a single column X3 and formatting X3 as datetime using as.POSIXct.

---

There's a hypothetical case in which it's not 100% clear what behavior you expect but it might be different from the code above does. This would apply if there there could be an id (X1) and date  combination that has for example 5 observations / rows and in three of them the time is the same and in two the time are different. The code above would result in X4 all the same for all observations of that id-date combination. If you don't want that, you could use the modified code below. I'll also provide a modified example to demonstrate the behavior.

First, let's create a new data set test3 and modify it so that for `X1 == 3162932` and `date == 2014-01-03` there are 4 time entries: 2 are the same (so for those the X4 should be replaced by its max) and 2 are different (so for those we should replace X4 with their sum of X4s).

```
test3 <- test2
test3$X1[1:4] <- "3162932"
test3$X3[2] <- "2014-01-03 8:47"

> test3
       X1         X2               X3  X4  # all 4 first rows have the same id
1 3162932 2014-01-03  2014-01-03 8:47  31   #   the first two are 
2 3162932 2014-01-03  2014-01-03 8:47  26   #     same id, same date, same time
3 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 10:11   4   #   this and the next are
4 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 11:44  32   #     same id, same date, different times
5 5374073 2014-01-04  2014-01-04 11:7  24
6 7427514 2014-01-03  2014-01-03 11:1 132
7 2377939 2014-01-11   2014-01-11 2:6  50
8 2377939 2014-01-11  2014-01-11 2:58  16
9 4081399 2014-01-07  2014-01-07 8:42  66
```

Here's how you could handle it as I think you'd like (but again, you haven't really specified that):

```
test3 %>%
  separate(X3, into = c("date", "time"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.Date(., format = "%Y-%m-%d")), X2, date) %>%
  group_by(X1, date, time) %>%
  mutate(X4 = max(X4), check = n() == 1L) %>%
  group_by(X1, date) %>%
  mutate(X4 = ifelse(n_distinct(time) > 1L & check, sum(X4[check]), X4)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  unite(X3, date:time, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(X3 = as.POSIXct(X3)) %>%
  select(ID = X1, Date = X2, DateTime = X3, Value = X4)

Source: local data frame [9 x 4]

       ID       Date            DateTime Value
1 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 08:47:00    31    # replaced by max
2 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 08:47:00    31    # replaced by max
3 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 10:11:00    36    # replaced by sum of 4 + 32
4 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 11:44:00    36    # replaced by sum of 4 + 32
5 5374073 2014-01-04 2014-01-04 11:07:00    24
6 7427514 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 11:01:00   132
7 2377939 2014-01-11 2014-01-11 02:06:00    66
8 2377939 2014-01-11 2014-01-11 02:58:00    66
9 4081399 2014-01-07 2014-01-07 08:42:00    66
```

Comment: That `sum(unique())` seems troublesome. What if they have the same X4 value at two different times on the same day?

Comment: If you try with `test3<-test2; test3[9, "X4"]<-41`, you get 41 for both rows 7 and 9 but it seems like you should be getting 82.

Comment: It is used in dplyr (and other packages) to create a pipe of several operations where the modified data is passed on from one to the next. See for example the [introduction to dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), especially the section about "chaining".

Comment: @pak, you first need to install and load the packages dplyr and tidyr to use this code

Comment: @docendodiscimus, I understand that, I'd just never seen the %>% operator before, that's useful.

Comment: @docendodiscimus the code worked earlier but not when my date format is different :( I have updated my question with the new format....

Comment: Well that's because you have a different date format in the new data set than in the original. Also, your new date format is ambiguous, please indicate whether `2014-01-03` in your new format is january 3, 2014 or march 1 2014.

Comment: @Science11, your expected output for the new data doesn't follow your own criteria. For example: for the date `2014-01-03` (same date) all X3 times are different, so according to your 3rd rule, the X4s in thos rows should be replaced by their sum which is what you see my function doing (resulting in 225). You should make clear why this is not what you want.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I see where things got messy....Id # - date - time...these three......., case 1)  same ID # - same date - different time - sum(X4) case 2) same ID # - same date- same time - max(X4)......what is happening is somehow the code is excluding the id # and just adding based on date..... it should consider (ID# + date + time)

Comment: In that case it's an easy fix. Just add the X1 column to the grouping variables.. See my update

Comment: @Science11, you're welcome. Please see my additional edit and example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly simpler logic, implemented using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(test2)[, tmp := NA]

test2[, c("X4", "tmp") := if (.N > 1) list(max(X4), TRUE), by=.(X1, X3)] ## (1)
test2[is.na(tmp), X4 := sum(X4), by=.(X1, gsub(" .*$", "", X3))]         ## (2)
#         X1         X2               X3  X4 tmp
# 1: 1491930 2014-01-03  2014-01-03 8:47  31  NA
# 2: 3162932 2014-01-03  2014-01-03 9:40  30  NA
# 3: 3162932 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 10:11  30  NA
# 4: 4092879 2014-01-03 2014-01-03 11:44  32  NA
# 5: 5374073 2014-01-04  2014-01-04 11:7  24  NA
# 6: 7427514 2014-01-03  2014-01-03 11:1 132  NA
# 7: 2377939 2014-01-11   2014-01-11 2:6  66  NA
# 8: 2377939 2014-01-11  2014-01-11 2:58  66  NA
# 9: 4081399 2014-01-07  2014-01-07 8:42  66  NA
```

1. Convert `test2` from data.frame to data.table by reference (without any additional copy). Now `test2` is a data.table on which we can use data.table syntax. And then we add a new (dummy) column (as a marker) with `NA`.
2. Aggregate by `X1` and `X3` columns. If there are more than one row, those rows fall under your first condition. We've to replace those rows alone by their maximum values for `X4`. We do that in (1), but in addition, we also update the dummy column for those rows to TRUE.
3. Then, we group by `X1` and just the date part of `X3`, but only on the rows that are not modified in the previous step. These satisfy your second condition. And we replace `X4` with sum of all values in that group.

This should also take care of the case where you have rows satisfying both conditions for a given `X1` and date.

If necessary you can remove the `tmp` column by setting it to `NULL`:

```
test2[, tmp := NULL]
```